# How to flag an "accept my answer and upvote it" comment

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I have seen some users who provide an answer, then add a comment "If it works don't forget to accept my answer and upvote it".

On seeing that type of comment, I get frustrated and try to flag it. I don't know which option to choose from the below list.

[image]

Comment: why do you get frustrated? if the answer solved the problem, wouldn't the fact that it's accepted help others who stumbled upon the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment is "Not Constructive".  It's not adding positive value to the post.

Comment: Or maybe `other...` and then explain what's wrong?

Comment: @devnull I've always flagged these as NC and they've been appropriately dealt with.  I don't see a need to use "other" here, not that doing so would be "wrong".

Comment: I just wanted to know.  I've usually flagged those as _other_.  Thanks for letting me know that NC is ok (it'll save some time :).

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when flagging such comments. One or two are OK (I'd probably pick 'not constructive' because, well, it's not a constructive comment. Or it's 'obsolete' if it's already been accepted) but any more and you're just going to add loads of flags to the already massive flag queue.

Don't go hunting for these posts, only flag them when you find them organically, and only then if you really feel you must.

If you flag too many they'll just all get declined and that'll go against your flag score, so ask yourself if you really need to have these comments removed or not.

Comment: _If you flag too many they'll just all get declined_  I'm not sure sure where you got this.  I have 100 comment flags a day and I typically use them and they rarely are declined, do you have some source that states these will all be declined?

Comment: @bluefeet: Yes, source is me. I'm a mod on UX. Admittedly we don't get anywhere near as many comment flags there as SO does, if one person decided to take it upon themself to flag 200 comments in one day that wouldn't go down well. Mods have better things to do than trawl through comment flags raised by people just trying to up their flag score.

Comment: Possibly on a smaller site I could see this potentially being an issue then, but I am actively trying to clean-up the site when I flag comments not trying to up my flag score.

Comment: @bluefeet: I'm more thinking of the big sites like SO. Comment flags can only be handled by diamond mods, they don't go into any review queue. Flagging comments takes time away from handling 'proper' mod flags.